# Apostrophes positions

Tags: sql

I know that my code have some unecessary part, but my main issue is related to the apostrophes' positioning

```
DECLARE
@cc1 VARCHAR(MAX)

SET cc1 = 

'
SELECT
STRING_AGG(CAST( N' UPDATE [db].[dbo].[Main_table] WITH (TABLOCK) SET ' AS nvarchar(MAX)) 
+QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME,'['']')  +N' = NULL WHERE '
+QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME,'['']') ,+N' = '''''
) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
'

PRINT(cc1)
```

I have almost tried everything, but I always get error and I can't figure it out that where should I have to adjust the code.

Desired

Comment: So... what's the error? Straight away `SET cc1 =` should be `SET @cc1 =`

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near ' AS nvarchar(MAX)) 
+QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME,'.
Msg 128, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
The name "cc1" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.

Comment: Guessing you should be doing `select @cc1=string_agg...`

Comment: Tried and not worked :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @cc1 NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cc1 = STRING_AGG(CAST( N' UPDATE [db].[dbo].[Main_table] WITH (TABLOCK) SET ' AS nvarchar(MAX)) 
    + QuoteName(COLUMN_NAME,'['']')  + N' = NULL WHERE '
    + QuoteName(COLUMN_NAME,'['']') ,+ N' = '''';'
) 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

PRINT(@cc1)
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I have made a small research and know I understand what was my fault. Thanks once again!